# jQuery Mobile Ajax: change class if page has been seen before

Tags: jquery, ajax, class, mobile

Im making a app with JQM framework.
Im looking for a jQuery command to change a class or ID of an element in page X, if the user has been on page X before - Is that possible?

Comment: Save a status of the user and then act accordingly. You can save the status using sessions for example

Comment: doesnt ajax make a history of pages loaded? wouldnt it be easier to look there?

Answer (score 0):

Yes using cookies. Use this [plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) and if the browser accepts them,
see the following function:

```
function checkIfHasBeenHereBefore(){
 if($.cookie("IHaveBeenHereBefore")=="t")
    {
      console.log("Have been here before");
    }
 else $.cookie("IHaveBeenHereBefore","t");
}
```

Thats it, replace the console.log with what you want.
You can find more information about writing cookies [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery).

Written under jQuery 1.9. (It should be supported till )

Comment: its for a native mobile app with cordova - i dont know if that will support it?

Comment: Then replace the cookies collection with you own cookie implementation. Without cookies (or some other form of local storage) this cannot be done as far as I know. (Not client side anyways)